# База данных в боте на питоне

Tags: python, бот

Написал бота на питоне. Как при старте проверить есть ли id пользователя в боте? Если есть, то не записывать и продолжить выполнение кода, если нет, то записать и продолжить выполнение кода. Если можно, то пример кода. Я учусь. Библиотека py-telegram-bot-api. И если можно попроще. Спасибо.

Comment: Смотрели `sqlite3`?

Comment: @gil9red пока разбираюсь, но не особо могу понять. Вы можете помочь? Делаю как раз с sqlite3

Comment: Создаете подключение к базе, указывая путь к файлу (sqlite либо в файле хранится, либо в оперативной памяти), создаете таблицу. Когда нужно, добавляете в таблицу новые записи либо считываете из таблицы. Все это делается через запросы SQL -- `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT`, и т.п. Примеры: [1](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/get_actual_news_from_rss_ya/webserver/common.py#L20), [2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/98213b251308cd641811fb530a90064749875728/Dark%20Souls/ru.darksouls.wikia.com__fandom__bosses/main.py#L95)

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно

Comment: +1 за sqlite. В своем телеграм боте использовал его. Можете посмотреть [его код](https://github.com/dizballanze/m00dbot/blob/master/storage.py) в качестве примера